# Facebook like button add a default comment

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-like

I am using facebook like button (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), box count style. When user clicks on like it shows a pop over allowing user to add a comment and share on his feed.
Can we add a default comment in that box, trying from much time but no success yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by facebook. The commentbox is reserved for the users comment on the content being liked. You should instead use open graph meta-tags on your page to control how your content is displayed in the users newsfeed or wall. You can review the open graph tags here: http://ogp.me/